# Maintain passwords while switching from ASP.NET Membership to ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership, identityserver4

My company is planning to upgrade our applications from .NET Framework to .NET Core, and as part of that to upgrade from ASP.NET Membership to ASP.NET Core Identity server. I found a useful article on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/membership-to-core-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

However, there is a sub-note with massive implications:

> After completion of this script, the ASP.NET Core Identity app created
>   earlier is populated with Membership users. Users need to change their
>   passwords before logging in.

We can't ask 600,000 users to change their password as part of this migration. However, the membership passwords are one-way hashed, so we can't retrieve them and then migrate them. So I'm wondering how we would go about maintaining our existing users' passwords with the new Identity Server approach.

Comment: What encryption are you using? FormsAuthentication?

Comment: Yes, this was used traditionally for an old ASP.NET web forms application with cookie-based forms authentication.

Comment: We had the same problem. We were using FormsAuthentication, unfortunately it is obsolete in .NET Core. My colleague wrote this to make it work in Core: https://github.com/synercoder/FormsAuthentication

Comment: I'm not worried about supporting forms authentication going forward, we're going to retire this web application and use an AngularJs app instead. I'm worried about migrating the users' passwords so that they work in Identity Server.

Comment: I believe forms authentication uses SHA1 encryption, all the stuff in Core does not support SHA1. So you might need rehash all the passwords or support forms authentication or write a custom password validator of sorts. Good luck

Comment: It looks like you'll need to find the source code for the membership password hashing algorithm and pull that into your new project as an `IPasswordHasher<TUser>` implementation. I suggest storing the old password hash in a separate column so that you can rehash any existing passwords into the new format once they've been verified using the old algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did this quite recently.

We had a legacy .net membership system and needed to import about 10k users over to asp.net identity.   I first created an extra column in the asp .net identity core user table when i copied all of the users from the system i brought their legacy password with them.

Then when the user logged in the first time.  I first checked if the legacy password existed if it did then i validated them against that and update the  password on asp. net identity core and deleted the legacy password. This way all of the users ported their passwords to the new system without even realizing it.

I am going to try and explain how i did it but the code is a bit crazy.

I actually added two columns to the applicationuser table

```
public string LegacyPasswordHash { get; set; }
public string LegacyPasswordSalt { get; set; }
```

ApplicationSignInManager -> CheckPasswordSignInAsync method does a check if the user is a legacy user

**ApplicationSignInManager**

```
public override async Task<SignInResult> CheckPasswordSignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password, bool lockoutOnFailure)
        {
        ........

            if (user.IsLegacy)
            {
                Logger.LogDebug(LoggingEvents.ApplicationSignInManagerCheckPasswordSignInAsync, "[user.Id: {user.Id}] is legacy.", user.Id);
                var results = await new LoginCommand(_logger, _userManager, user, password, lockoutOnFailure).Execute();
                if (results.Succeeded)
                {
                    await ResetLockout(user);
                    return SignInResult.Success;
                }
            }
            else if (await UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
            {
                await ResetLockout(user);
                return SignInResult.Success;
            }

            ........
        }
```

**Login Command**

```
 public class LoginCommand
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ApplicationUser _user;
        private readonly string _password;
        private readonly bool _shouldLockout;

        public LoginCommand(ILogger logger, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationUser user, string password, bool shouldLockout)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _user = user;
            _password = password;
            _shouldLockout = shouldLockout;
        }

        public async Task<SignInResult> Execute()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Found User: {_user.UserName}");
            if (_user.IsLegacy)
                return await new LegacyUserCommand(_logger, _userManager, _user, _password, _shouldLockout).Execute();
            if (await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(_user, _password))
                return await new CheckTwoFactorCommand(_logger, _userManager, _user).Execute();
            if (_shouldLockout)
            {
                return await new CheckLockoutCommand(_logger, _userManager, _user).Execute();
            }
            _logger.LogDebug($"Login failed for user {_user.Email} invalid password");
            return SignInResult.Failed;
        }
    }
```

**LegacyUserCommand**

```
  public class LegacyUserCommand
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        private readonly ApplicationUser _user;
        private readonly string _password;
        private bool _shouldLockout;

        public LegacyUserCommand(ILogger logger, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationUser user, string password, bool shouldLockout)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _user = user;
            _password = password;
            _shouldLockout = shouldLockout;
        }

        public async Task<SignInResult> Execute()
        {
            try
            {
                if (_password.EncodePassword(_user.LegacyPasswordSalt) == _user.LegacyPasswordHash)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.LegacyUserCommand, "Legacy User {_user.Id} migrating password.", _user.Id);
                    await _userManager.AddPasswordAsync(_user, _password);
                    _user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    _user.LegacyPasswordHash = null;
                    _user.LegacyPasswordSalt = null;
                    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(_user);
                    return await new CheckTwoFactorCommand(_logger, _userManager, _user).Execute();
                }
                if (_shouldLockout)
                {
                    _user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(_user);
                    _logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.LegacyUserCommand, "Login failed for Legacy user {_user.Id} invalid password. (LockoutEnabled)", _user.Id);
                    await _userManager.AccessFailedAsync(_user);
                    if (await _userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(_user))
                        return SignInResult.LockedOut;
                }

                _logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.LegacyUserCommand, "Login failed for Legacy user {_user.Id} invalid password", _user.Id);
                return SignInResult.Failed;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError(LoggingEvents.LegacyUserCommand, "LegacyUserCommand Failed for [_user.Id: {_user.Id}]  [Error Message: {e.Message}]", _user.Id, e.Message);
                _logger.LogTrace(LoggingEvents.LegacyUserCommand, "LegacyUserCommand Failed for [_user.Id: {_user.Id}] [Error: {e}]", _user.Id, e);
                return SignInResult.Failed;
            }
        }
    }
```

TOP TIP: [SecurityStamp] an not be NULL!

Comment: So the extra column you created was for their old hashed password? How exactly did you validate against that old password (code would be helpful)? Also, how did you update the password in identity core when you don't know what the actual password is (it's a one-way hash)?

Comment: 1. Hash and salt  2. the user types in their login you have the password its submitted in the form you have it in clear text you just need to save it.  3.   I hope this makes some sense. Let me know.   4.

Comment: Do you have the code for EncodePassword the you could post? That appears to be the most important part!

Answer (score 0):

We've recently migrated from various legacy systems and since they all used various forms of hashing passwords, rather than trying to port that logic over we customised the password authentication code to allow it to do a call out to an API exposed by each legacy system. Each user migrated from such a system had the API URL stored against it.

When a migrated user signs in for the first time we make a call out to said service (which itself was secured using a bearer token and a restricted integration scope) to do the password authentication that first time. If we get a success response then we hash the password in our own format and that is used forever more.

The downside of this is that you do have to keep the old system up (with this new API bolted on) pretty much forever. Since it's all .Net you may fare better by keeping it all in-proc and copying the migrated user hashed passwords to your new DB, assuming you can get an implementation of the old hashing scheme running inside .Net Core.